# Apply two different classes with panel class depending on the condition in Angular material

Tags: angular, angular-material, mat-select

I am using mat-select of Angular material. It has panelclass property that can be used to apply class. In parent component I have to style the drop down. The issue is :- I have to apply dynamic class to panelclass but type of panel class is string.

```
<mat-select panelClass="customClass ? customClass : select-position"> 
</mat-select>
```

I want to do something like this but its is not working and in DOM showing complete things inside "" as string

I have attcahed screenshot of generated HTML

[image]

Comment: did you try [ngCLass](https://angular.io/api/common/NgClass) ?

Comment: Just wrap the `panelClass` in the [square brackets](https://angular.io/guide/property-binding#binding-to-a-property), otherwise right-hand side won't be treated as expression but as a string. e.g. `[panelClass]="isCustom ? 'custom' : 'select-position'"`

Comment: Yes that was the issue 
Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

Could you try the notation with the square brackets and the class names in quotes like this:

```
<mat-select [panelClass]="customClass ? 'customClass' : 'select-position'"> </mat-select>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use it in 2 ways to bind the values:

1. Using property binding (Wrapping the panelClass with square brackets [])

```
<mat-select [panelClass]="customClass ? 'customClass' : 'select-position'"> 
</mat-select>
```

2. Using interpolation (Wrapping the condition in {{}})

```
<mat-select panelClass="{{ customClass ? 'customClass' : 'select-position' }}"> </mat-select>
```